# Disable CPU frequency scaling on Lenovo Laptop

Tags: cpu-load, cpufreq, scaling, frequency

I have a bug where my CPU frequency is scaling down every few hours or so. This happens when:

1. I'm on AC power
2. scaling governor is on 'Performance'

What do you have to do to disable CPU frequency scaling? I know you can manually force the min CPU frequency uder `/sys/devices/system/cpu`, however I really want a permanent solution so I don't have to be constantly changing the CPUfreq values.

Comment: It's normal that your CPU's frequency goes down every once in a while even on AC power, as actual CPU loads vary over time. Normally it is best to leave cpu frequency untouched, but you can always change it permanently by following ayan4m1's advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure it's not going to interfere, remove the `powernowd` package from your system. From a terminal, run:

`sudo apt-get remove powernowd`

After that, or if you don't have that package installed, install `rcconf` by running:

`sudo apt-get install rcconf`

Then run `sudo rcconf` and press space with the `ondemand` service highlighted to disable it. This service controls CPU frequency scaling. Press enter to save and quit. To manually stop it once, you can run `sudo /etc/init.d/ondemand stop`.

Comment: You can also set a specific cpu frequency governor by changing that script and setting the governor to say, "performance" or "conservative" rather than "ondemand".

Answer (score 1):

I guess *ayan4m1* explain everything to remove cpu frequency scaling from your box, except by one little detail: If you remove cpu scaling (or set it for performance service), then you will increase energy consumption (even in AC power).