# Disable CPU frequency scaling and halts in Lenovo G50-80

Tags: performance, cpu, cpufreq, scaling

I have a Lenovo G50-80 with an i5-5200U CPU running Ubuntu 16.04.2 on `4.4.0-79-generic`. I would like to disable CPU frequency scaling and processor halts for running a project. I have installed `i7z` and its output tells me that my CPU frequency varies a lot and my processor goes into C1 and C3 states when I'm not using it.

I have tried to change the governor from `powersave` to `performance` by following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/523690/440733). Running `cpufreq-info` tells me that `powersave` and `performance` are available governors and `performance` is set as the governor. Yet the output of `i7z` shows varying frequency and C1 states being in use. I have tried every other answer in the thread as well as from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12942/disable-cpu-frequency-scaling-on-lenovo-laptop). Going through the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling) doesn't help either.

TL,DR; change governor from `powersave` to `performance` does not have any effect

Quick Edit: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844680/disable-hyperthreading-p-state-and-c-state-drivers-and-cpu-frequency-scaling) guy has the same issue too.

Edit: Here's the dump of my `cpufreq-info` for one of the logical cores.

```
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 500 MHz - 2.70 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 500 MHz and 2.70 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.18 GHz.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using intel-pstate, the default for Ubuntu, there are a bunch of settings for the `cpupower` program:

```
cpupower frequency-set -u 3.10GHz -d 3.10 GHz -g performance
cpupower set -b 0
```

Modify the `-u` and `-l` options to suit your processor.

To prevent C1 state, add the following options to your kernel boot parameters

`intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=1`

This is done by editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding these parameters to the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Comment: Nope does not work. Also your original commands were wrong

Comment: @RecursiveCursive Corrected first commands - sorry about that.

Comment: @RecursiveCursive Checked on my system again, although this does not indicate too much as I have read some systems do not support the boot parameters.  Did you `sudo update-grub` after the edit to grub, and reboot?

Comment: Yeah I did `sudo update-grub` and restarted. I can't find any sort of options in the BIOS to disable frequency scaling. As for c-states I added `intel_pstate=disable` and managed to get C0 to 100%. C1 however shows random values with a max of 30% though

Comment: the `pstate` disable reverts back to cpufreq_utilities, rather than cpupower utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly to get it working for the `generic` kernel. But I installed `4.4.0-79-lowlatency` kernel and installed `linux-tools-4.4.0-79-lowlatency` `linux-tools-lowlatency`. Then using

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

I was able to disable C states higher than C0 and have a constant frequency of 2493.18 MHz.